# Define a period of time in PHP Carbon

Tags: php, date, laravel

I'm working on a food ordering web app (using Laravel), when a restaurant owner signs-up (to list their restaurant) and logs in, among other things, they'r asked to set the periods for which their restaurant will be closed and unable to take or deliver orders.

For the sake of simplicity, say that one of the restaurants always shuts at 01:30 am Fridays and remains shut until 09:00 am Sundays, same schedule every week.

Obviously when the hungry user visits the site Saturday night, this specific restaurant listing will be "Unavailable at the moment, opens 9 am Sunday" (Terrible UX, I know..)

How can I make such fixed interval comparison in [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)?
In plain English the `IF` statment would be something like: `If right-now is anywhere between a (Friday 1:30 am ) and a (Sunday 9:00 am), then return false`

I know the `between()` method does something very similar, but it compares specific dates only, not intervals of repeated days and hours.

```
$first = Carbon::create(2014, 9, 5, 1);
$second = Carbon::create(2014, 9, 5, 5);
var_dump(Carbon::create(2014, 9, 5, 3)->between($first, $second));          // bool(true)
```

Ps. I know Laravel has it's own implementation of Carbon and is called via `Date`, but if somone knows a solution in Carbon, the Laravel implementation will be easy.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `parse()` with the underlying power of PHP's `strtotime()`?

```
$friday = Carbon::parse('last friday 1:30 am');
$sunday = Carbon::parse('sunday 9:00 am');
return ! Carbon::now()->between($friday, $sunday, false);
```

(The third argument decides if `<` and `>` or `<=` and `>=` is used. `false` means `<` and `>`. The default value is `true`)

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks man. Oh, btw, the  `false` doesn't work, It's not a big deal since I can invert the bool outcome manually anyways. Would be interesting if someone knows why. (tested only inside Laravel).

Comment: You're welcome. Looks I misread the documentation on the third parameter. See the updated answer...